# Post data onto different APIs in React JS from a single form using axios

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, post, axios

Eg. I want to post the name and email into an API and their address into a different API from the same .js file.
How should I go on around this.

Comment: Add your sample code. you can call any number of API calls from a component. We need to see the your implementation to answer more perfectly

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Create a function and pass to it the values you want to send via api then inside your function body create as many as you want of api calls.
In `ES6`:

```
const myFunction = (name, email, address) => {
    axios.post('apiString1', {name, email}).then(response => {console.log(response)});
    axios.post('apiString2', {address}).then(response => {console.log(response)});
}
```